# Problems in MinGW when statically linking SFML libraries

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a program that compiles with no errors under Linux, but when I compile it for Windows using MinGW it can't run as it says that it requires some DLL's next to it. So I decided to statically link it, but it outputs some errors:

```
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-window-s.a(WindowImplWin32.o):WindowImplWin32.cpp:(.text+0x146e): undefined reference to `__Unwind_Resume'
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-window-s.a(WindowImplWin32.o):WindowImplWin32.cpp:(.text+0x17d0): more undefined references to `__Unwind_Resume' follow
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-window-s.a(WindowImplWin32.o):WindowImplWin32.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-window-s.a(Joystick.o):Joystick.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `___gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems like it has some external dependencies. What are those, and how do I link them?

**Edit:**

Here's what I put in the command line:

> i586-mingw32msvc-g++ "./main.cpp" -o "./win32.exe" /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-graphics-s.a /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libsfml-window-s.a /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libm.a /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libmsvcr90.a

**Help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Could you post your compile line? The errors look like what happens when you try to compile/link C++ code using gcc instead of g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too recently.

It's that SFML is compiled with DW2 exception handling, but the default MinGW cross-compiler (in the Debain and Ubuntu repos) uses SJLJ, and these are not compatible with each other. I had to build my own cross-compiler with DW2 exception handling, and that works flawlessly. Alternatively, you can build SFML itself with your existing SJLJ compiler, so SFML will be SJLJ too.

I decided to build a DW2 compiler, because it is the more modern method, and it was a good exercise too.

Comment: Well... I could send you my own-built DW2 cross-compiler, but I can't guarantee that it will work on your machine aswell...

And I planned to write about the build process in my blog, but that's in Hungarian.

Comment: Oh, if you aren't going to compile it for Windows from Linux, (so you aren't going to cross-compile), then you just have to download a MinGW package, which uses DW2, so there's no need for compiler building. The TDM edition of MinGW has both versions packaged IMHO, but the "stock" MinGW is DW2. But FIXME. For example CodeBlocks includes a TDM edition with SJLJ, that's why it doesn't work correctly at start. Excuse me, I thought you want to cross-compile.

Comment: I do want to cross-compile, but I think I'll try compiling it on Windows as it is probably easier than building a cross-compiler. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use g++ instead of gcc, should fix it. Start from scratch (clean all before rebuilding). Another option might be what's described in [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-05/msg00137.html), assuming you already use g++ and still get it.